# Python: Force-Cast Long to Int32

Tags: python, numpy

I am generating a random seed.

Python3 grinds to a halt if I:

```
numpy.random.seed(time.time_ns())

# or

numpy.random.seed(int(time.time_ns())

# and

numpy.random.seed(numpy.int32(time.time_ns())
```

With "num type was expected to be int32" errors in the first two tries, and "invalid cast from a 64bit number to a 32bit number" in the last.

How do I force this to occur without, say, modulo by 2**32?

Comment: `time.time_ns()` returns an `int`, so the first two are equivalent. `np.random.seed(time.time_ns())` gives me a `ValueError: Seed must be between 0 and 2**32 - 1`, so I guess you have to ensure that the value fits inside 32 bits. Your `...%2**32` works and I don't know what problem you have with it.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch I'd rather it be a formal property I set (even if it is process under the hood).  Using math in python3 vs using discrete logic in some other language is a big style change for a lot of people.

Comment: `time.time_ns()` carries more information (64 bits) than `numpy.random.seed(...)` can use (32 bit). So if you really want to use `time.time_ns()`, you need some form of information reduction. A "lot of people" are unfamiliar with this problem and I suspect a comment would help more than finding some other solution.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch In any other language I can cast the number. In python, I must perform a pure math function.  This is ridiculous.  What is the way to cast an int64 to an int32 as a formal step (O(1), conceptually), rather than this functional clause?  On the one hand, you have a sheet of paper that you stick into an envelope, and cut off the remainder... on the other you have some complex body of knowledge and cleverness that amounts to the same thing, sort of (it is `/2**32 - 1`, actually, and completely wrong without the `-1`).  Why is the latter a superior approach?

Comment: I'm not here to defend how Python (a high-level language) makes the user handle low-level operations like unsafe explicit typecasts from int64 to int32. As long as you don't set the random seed many times, the time complexity of this operation is practically irrelevant (changing the seed to an int32 most probably is slower than converting an int64 to int32 anyway). And the mathematical correctness of `num%32` is practically irrelevant in this case since setting the random seed to the current time in milliseconds is supposed to be unpredictable.

Comment: If you want the Python-equivalent of `(int) num` in C, import `ctypes` and use `ctypes.c_int32(num).value`.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch the time complexity is irrelevant.  The point is that `(x/2**32) - 1` is the definition of a low level fix, whereas casting the integer `you_shall_be_int32(x)` is the definition of a high level approach.  And the question is for the high level approach.

Comment: Then we have different impressions on what high-level operations are. Anyway, `ctypes.c_int32(num).value` seems to be the thing you are looking for, then. :)